# Syncing email replies back to a case in Salesforce

Tags: email2case

I'm wondering if it is possible to sync email replies to cases back to Salesforce natively?

I know that when I send an email from a case, it places a unique ID in the footer and if I send it to the Email2Case address it attaches to the case.  However, is it possible to complete this same loop with personal email addresses?

I assume that Salesforce For Outlook is involved, but haven't found anything in the documentation or online that would specify how to set this up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. You'll need to ether write an apex email handler or buy a app on appexchange. I'm in the process of creating a handler for this.

Checkout http://sforcehacks.blogspot.ca/
This guy has a pretty good solution, you may need to tweak a bit, but it's a start.